# Outgoing webhook in slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am new to slack and I am developing a outgoing webhook in slack.
My requirement is as soon as some words like STOP, START are typed in channel then trigger must happen and has to be posted to my web hook.

I dont want this trigger to fire for all messages and only for particular message as START and STOP

I found this [app](https://slack.com/apps/A0F7VRG6Q-outgoing-webhooks?tab=more_info) but in the app page itself they are saying its legacy and recommending not to use this app and suggesting to use Event API

In the Event API I am not seeing any events that can be triggered for particular word.I am seeing message:im, message:groups but this will fire for all the messages I feel.